# function returning letter column and value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been reading in different websites how to create a function that gets a string as argument which is the name of a column in excel(The name of the column is defined by the value found in row 4;name, status, phone,etc) and returns two values; The column letter(A,B,C,D,etc.) AND the column title(name, status, phone). So far I have this function that returns the letter of the column where the title is found but I am not sure how to modify this function so it returns the column letter AND the column title as well. The argument for this function is the column title which is retrieved from an array. Probably I cannot use one argument and get two values, no sure. I would appreciate any help. Thank you

```
 Function ColumnLetters(r As Range) As String
 Dim i As String
 i = r.Address(False, False)
 ColumnLetters = Left(i, Len(i) - Len(Format(r.row, "0")))
 End Function
```

Comment: You can return an array instead of returning a string value

Comment: Or return a Struct.  Or return the values using ByRef parameters. Really you should probably use two different functions: one for the column letter and one for the heading.

Comment: Yes Tim, I have it very similar to what you mentioned. This is the line of the code; HeadersCategories(x) = ColumnLetters(foundRange). HeadersCateroties is the array for the headers and the ColumnLetters is the function that returns the column letter. But I thought I could do it both in one function. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim a
    a = ColumnInfo(Range("D10"))
    msgbox "Column: " & a(0) & "   Header: " & a(1)

End sub


Function ColumnInfo(r As Range)

     Set r = r.Cells(1)EntireColumn 

     ColumnInfo = Array(Replace(r.Cells(1).Address(False, False), "1", ""), _
                        r.Cells(4).Value)
End Function
```

Comment: Ok, I am checking it.